# counterexample to RH; how big would it have to be?

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

If the Riemann hypothesis is false, then there has to be a first counterexample for  $\zeta(z)=0$ in the critical strip with $\Re(z) \ne \frac{1}{2}$.  For such a counterexample, how large would $T=|\Im(z)|$ have to be?

On the one hand, we've only computed the first 10 trillion or so zeros, so it could be the very next one.  On the other hand, assuming Odlyzko comments below are correct, there is no hope for disproving the RH by actually computing a counterexample.  Andrew Odlyzko is quoted in "Prime Obsession" (by John Derbyshire, highly recommended book),

"For the entire range for which zeta has been studied--which is to say, for arguments on the critical line up to around 10^23 -- S mainly hovers between -1 and 1.  The largest known value is around 3.2.  There are strong reasons to believe that if S were ever to get up around 100, then the RH might be in trouble.  The operative word is "might"; S attaining a value near 100 is a *necessary* condition for the RH to be in trouble, but not a sufficient one."

Could values of the S function ever get that big? "...Atle Selberg proved in 1946 that S is unbounded... Probably around t equals $10^{10^{10000}}$"

So then the first counterexample cannot be "the next" zero.  Is this rigorously provable?  Or could the S function jump immediately to values near 100 for the very next zero which isn't on the critical line?  I'm also looking for a link to Selberg's S function.

**edit** The S function is just the log of zeta in the critical strip.  Since $\zeta(z)$ goes to 1 as $\Re(z)$ increases, we take the logarithm from the positive side.  here's a link: http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~goldston/MyS(t).pdf

$$S(T) = \frac{1}{\pi }\arg\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+iT) $$

The [wikipedia artcle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) talks about the growth and average magnitude of S(T) as well.   $S(T)$ jumps by $\pm1$ at zeros of the $\zeta$ function; and mainly hovers between -1 and 1; from Derbyshire's book, the largest known value is 3.2  So why would the magnitude of S(T) be connected with possible counterexamples to the RH?  I know at a counter example, $S(T)$ would jump by $\pm 2$.  Anyway, this is all new stuff to me; Gram points, S(T); fun stuff.

Comment: In 1914, studying the properties of the error in the Prime Number Theorem, Littlewood have observed that there are "behavior irregularities". Today we know that the first instance of one of these irregularities is about at $10^{316}.$ Obviously this is not a proof, but it shows how could be computationally hard find a exceptional zero.

Comment: Was not it proven that the Riemann hypothesis is true?

Comment: @moti RH is definitely a hypothesis; not proven.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis

Comment: @MarcoCantarini : and did you get what are those irregularities (intuitively) ? and I get $S(T)$ is meant to be what is mentioned here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function

Comment: @user1952009 The logarithmic integral $\int_0^x \frac{1}{\ln(x)} dx$ is a slight overestimate for $\pi(x)$ (the prime counting function).  It has been proven that there is a counter example somewhere near $10^{316} \approx  \ln(727.95132478)$ if you look up skewe's number.  Saouter-Demichel calculated this estimate using the first 20 millions zeros of the Riemann zeta function, all of which have real part 0.5.  So it is related to my question, since it shows counter examples happen for very large numbers for the $\zeta$ function.  http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~roger/math31022/Beamer1.pdf

Comment: what ?? I know all this in your pdf, but it doesn't talk of $N(T)$ and $S(T)$ the non-trivial zeros counting functions mentioned in  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function which I suppose your question is about

Comment: and $\psi(x) = x - \sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho} = \sum_{p^k \le x} \ln p$ is easier to study than $\pi(x) = \sum_{p \le x} 1$ (the prime number theorem has been proven with $\psi(x)$, using that $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = -s \int_1^\infty \psi(x) x^{-s-1} dx$), and it is obvious that $h(x) = \psi(x) - x$ oscillates with the number of crossovers related with the imaginary part of the non-trivial zeros : the Riemann hypothesis is that $h(e^{u}) e^{-u/2}$ is a sum of sines plus an $\mathcal{O}(-u/2)$ term

Comment: @user1952009 apologies if what I responded was trivial. I personally don't know what the connection between S(t) and the Riemann Siegel $\theta(t)$ function is.  That would be my question.

Comment: what is $S(t)$ .. ?

Comment: @user1952009 I added the description of S(T).